# Typhoon Inject Property to a new object

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am start to use DI containers on iOS and I don't have idea how to inject property in this case:

Imagine we have:

**Assembly.m**

```
- (ClassA *)classA {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ClassA class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(url) with:@"http://inject:URL"];
    }];
}
```

And two classes

**ClassA**

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *url;
@end
```

**ClassB**

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end
```

And

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   ClassB *cB = [ClassB new]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",cB.url);
}
```

I want to where I create new object by ClassB, all objects has injection with url property from my DI container (assembly)
Yes I can add property to my ViewController and this injection works fine, but I need inject property to new object.

Maybe I don't understand all principles but I should ask. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (id)classAObject{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ClassA class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition){
                              [definition injectProperty:@selector(url) with:@"http://inject:URL"];
                          }];
}

- (id)classBObject{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withParent:[self classAObject] class:[ClassB class]];
}

KSTTestAssembly *assembly = [[KSTTestAssembly alloc] init];
[assembly activate];

id classB = [assembly classBObject];
```

**Bootstrapping Typhoon**

You can bootstrap Typhoon, and hold a reference to it, Typically in the AppDelegate. In other parts of the application, we don't want to obtain an instance of Typhoon directly:

- We're coupling our application directly to Typhoon
- This is not dependency injection, difficult to test, etc

So what we do instead is:

- Inject the assembly (or one of the assemblies, in a modular set-up) into the class where we need it. Once an assembly is activated, this will actually be an instance of `TyphoonComponentFactory` posing as an assembly.
- It will serve as a factory for emitting a built object graph.
- Typhoon's default scope is `ObjectGraph`. So, we don't hold any objects in memory - just recipes for building them. The object graph is instantiated just when we need it.
- In this way we can proceed from one object graph to another efficiently, and in a loosely coupled way.

**Example:**

```
- (RootViewController *)rootController
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[RootViewController class] 
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(assembly)];
    }];
}
```

The [documentation for this feature is here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

**Storyboards:**

If you like to use story boards and Objective-C, you can [use auto-injection macros on your view controllers](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Storyboards).

Comment: yes, its make sense and its work, but I don't like always gets this object from assembly. Where is work of dependency injection in this case?

Comment: @dev.nikolaz Why don't you like it? It's ok to use assembly(IoC-container) for getting some object. So DI it's a mechanism for injecting dependencies (in your case for property dependency) and it uses IoC-container which holds configuration settings.

Comment: yes u are right, this for configuration settings)) and at this moment this correctly answer. Big thx!

Comment: @dev.nikolaz Added some details about where to hold an instance of Typhoon, and how to avoid coupling directly to it in, eg, View Controllers. //@NikkitaErmolenko Thx for answering!